# How to create build system in Sublime Text 2, for deploying Rails apps via Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, sublimetext2

What I have:

```
{
  "cmd": ["git add . && git commit -m 'deploy' && git push && cap deploy"],
  "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}"
}
```

This command works in the terminal but not via `Ctrl+B` in Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cmd` entry expects an array of each token in the the command instead of the entire command string. It's better explained by an example. In your case:

```
"cmd": ["git", "add", ".", "&&", "git", "commit", "-m", "'deploy'", "&&", "git", "push", "&&", "cap", "deploy"]
```

However, a better approach is to create a separate script `deploy.sh` that performs all these tasks for you, then call that script for your sublime build file.

**deploy.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
git add . && git commit -m 'deploy' && git push && cap deploy
```

**deploy.sublime_build**:

```
{
  "cmd": ["deploy"],
  "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}"
}
```

[sublime build system documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html)

Comment: Thanks! But Sublime don't output anything in console =(

Comment: It does! If you hit `Ctrl + ~` Sublime will bring up its own console at the bottom of your page. Any output from the build system will be printed there.

Comment: Thanks, it's my fault, I enter wrong param "name" in sublime-build =)